# debian apt-get install fail after search success

Tags: debian, apt

I'm able to search a custom package:

```
apt-cache show testsingle    
Package: testSingle
    Version: 0.9.12-1
    Architecture: amd64
    Essential: no
    Maintainer: rpub.it
    Installed-Size: 1024
    Filename: ./testSingle_0.9.12-1_amd64.deb
    Size: 2850
    MD5sum: a1ea85d3090e3e56516430dd4ca15c50
    SHA1: 13f670881b1283fb54a256c2c2b3fd17d131e204
    SHA256: 47c98aa3779fd4e11c779b9ed66fd0e5cefffc0e61cb68939956db5f489b27a8
    Section: custom
    Priority: optional
    Description: test  Debian Deploy
    Description-md5: 734c5d7408c231c45ba5b1e3ea6e28fe
```

but after when i try to install I got

```
apt-get install  testSingle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testSingle
```

Is it possible to log better apt processing ?

Comment: How do you specify the source in apt? Note the trailing `/` is significant in apt sources.list: it tells apt if the file is in a simple directory or in a structured repository.

Comment: I used this line: 
deb http://devmongo36a01/Debian /

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks a lot * it was the pathname inside Packages.z*
I regenerated Packages.z with
amd64/testSingle_0.9.12-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Giacomo 
the root cause was in the usage of current directory

```
./testSingle_0.9.12-1_amd64.deb
```

Instead of using

```
amd64/testSingle_0.9.12-1_amd64.deb
```